# QChart set tick with uneven space

Tags: qchart

In QChart, how can I set tick with uneven space? In the example chart below, notice the first grid is smaller than others. How is it actually done? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [TickType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalueaxis.html#TickType-enum) of your [QValueAxis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalueaxis.html) to `QValueAxis::TicksDynamic`.

Then you can set a [tick anchor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalueaxis.html#tickAnchor-prop) (i.e. the value where the first tick should be placed, e.g. 80.0 in the example image you provided) and [tick intervals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalueaxis.html#tickInterval-prop) (the value between ticks, e.g. 2.5 in the example image)

Please note that dynamic ticks were only introducted in **Qt 5.12**.